# Blurring when sending GRAY8 video over UDP with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

These commands produce a video image that has blurring around the edge of the changing static in the bottom right corner. If I remove the GRAY8 format, the blurring disappears.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY8 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

[image]

Comment: It is even more pronounced when I change the test pattern to 'snow'.

Comment: Looks like UDP packet loss. Check docs on `rtpbin` for more robust RTP features or switch to a TCP based transmission protocol.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Do you know why it would work with color but not grayscale?

Comment: No, but packet loss isn't exactly deterministic.. But this could be a problem with the encoder itself if the rate control decides to spent not enough bits in that area. You need to investigate what you are dealing with.